# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

Sei que a pergunta é um pouco subjetiva, mas talvez alguém já tenha passado por isso e consiga me ajudar.

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em C#/Windows Forms/ADO.NET com banco de dados firebird.

O erro "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" estava sendo apresentado, de forma intermitente, em algumas funcionalidades do sistema. Reparei que estas funcionalidades estão ligadas a alguma transação de banco de dados (insert/update/delete).

Quando tentava debugar através de um servidor de desenvolvimento a aplicação não apresentava o erro. Não sabendo mais o que fazer, simplesmente reiniciei o IIS e a aplicação se estabilizou. Alguém já passou por isso?

Obs.: Li em um artigo (https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/810098) da Microsoft que o ADO.NET não foi totalmente testado em ambiente .NET Framework e que podem causar problemas intermitentes. Pensei que poderia estar relacionado a isto.

Comment: Só é subjetiva porque não tem informações suficientes. Se tivesse, ela seria bem objetiva, afinal, nada mais objetivo que um código e um erro claramente demonstrado. Isto é erro de programação ou de instalação.

Comment: Você poderia incluir na pergunta um exemplo de como esta funcionalidade está sendo feita , acredito que pode ajudar para resolver está pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

O link mencionado trata de erros intermitentes em ADO e ADO MD.
Esses problemas ocorrem porque a tecnologia compatível com o Framework .NET é a tecnologia ADO.NET.

O texto destaca: "Cuidado os ADO e os ADO MD não foram totalmente testados em um ambiente do Microsoft .NET Framework" e complementa com uma solução temporária até a completa migração de ADO para ADO.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri que em vários métodos do projeto, instâncias dos objeto FBCommand e FbDataReader não estavam utilizando o método dispose. Após implementar este método a aplicação se estabilizou.